# Fetching Data from JSON using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

I have created a fragment which if it is activated it will show MySQL data but it takes time to fetch the data and show it on a custom **ListView**.

I tried to implement **AsyncTask** so that while fetching the data you can do something else on the fragment while waiting but  am having this error.

> "FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException"

**Here is the code**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_markets,container,false);

    //lvMarkets.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Symbols,Prices,Balances));
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    final ListView lvMarkets = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvMarkets);
    final String c_androidid    =   Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    final Cursor rs = db.getID(c_androidid);
    rs.moveToFirst();
    final String c_login = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.c_login));

    AsyncTaskRunner taskRunner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    taskRunner.execute(c_login);
    lvMarkets.setAdapter(jAdapter);
    return rootView;
}

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        final String fin_login=params[0];
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                Log.d(debug,response);
                try
                {
                    jsonArray =new JSONArray(response);
                    jAdapter= new JsonAdapter(getActivity(),jsonArray,login);
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Log.d(debug,e.toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                Log.d(debug,error.toString());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String>getParams()
            {
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("c_login",fin_login);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(stringRequest);

        return fin_login;
    }
}
```

Hope someone could point out what went wrong with my code and someone could also point out on how to fetch data on online much more faster.

Thanks...

Comment: It would help a lot if you can provide the complete error logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this:
      private void parsingValues() {

    URL obj = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    try {
           //parameter to post
        String POST_PARAMS = "deviceos=" + deveiceOs + "&devicetype=" + deviceType +"&deviceid=" ;
        obj = new URL("Your URI");
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
           //getResponse
            String subsResponse = response.toString();
            final JSONObject responsesubs = new JSONObject(subsResponse);
          //Here your parsing process
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println("POST request not worked");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
// Call this method to your doinbackground of Asynhronous Task(parsingValues())
```